# How to I secure MySQL with QR code?

Tags: mysql, database, security, connection-string, qr-code

I heard MySQL remarks that MySQL connection string has security leak.
So I'm trying to make it secure.
How can I do this and
how can I use QR code with my MySQL database ?

I use this :

```
Server=address;Port=port;Database=database;Uid=user;Pwd=password
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A QR code is a visual representation of a string of bytes. By itself, it has no value for security. Any device can read the bytes and decode what's stored in them.

You could store an *encrypted* string in a QR code, so the reader would have to decrypt it. But you could also store the same encrypted string in a normal textual representation. The QR code is not the mechanism of security.

The most common way a MySQL connection string can be a security leak is if an unauthorized client can read the connection string in plain text. Connection strings typically exist in application source code. So if the client has access to your source code, it can read the connection string.

The solution is to store the sensitive parts of the connection string in another file, not in your source code. Your code would load the file at runtime and derive the user & password from it.